sim2real gap in robotic arm trajectory execution
Lately, I've been working on projects where I have to replicate an existing robot trajectory in a simulator. I'd like to keep this question generic, but I guess that each software has its own answers. For the sake of targeting as many roboticists as possible, let's say I am using moveit2, ros2_control and Ignition Gazebo Fortress.
Replicating the points of the trajectory is a feasible problem. These are basically direct and inverse kinematics problems. However, I observe discrepancies in the time it takes the robot to move through such trajectory between the real and simulated cases, sometimes in the order of seconds.
Assuming that one will always introduce errors at simulation time, I'd basically like to discuss the following aspects:

Where are the discrepancies?
Given those discrepancies, how to decrease the sim2real gap? What is the precision limit? E.g. is it possible to achieve an error of 0.1 s, or less?

Regarding the first question, I can think of errors and discrepancies in the physical description of the robot (mass, inertia, mechanical limits), the control parameters and strategies (the ros2_controller and the real controller computations are not exactly the same) and the physics engine parameters and computations. Also, there is no exact match on the instructions commanded to the robot, e.g. there is no direct translation of ABB's RAPID to moveit2.
